# Undefined is not an object (UIConstants)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In react-native I have this class(from kittenTricks):

```
  import {Platform} from 'react-native';

export class UIConstants {
  static AppbarHeight = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 44 : 56;
  static StatusbarHeight = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : 0;
  static HeaderHeight = UIConstants.AppbarHeight + UIConstants.StatusbarHeight;
}
```

Name of the class: AppConstants.js

The problem is when I try to export this class. I get this error:

```
undefined is not an object(evaluating 'UIConstants.AppbarHeight')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't refer to the same class duting its declaration. Try with defining heights earlier:

```
const appbarHeight = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 44 : 56;
const statusbarHeight = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : 0;

export class UIConstants {
  static AppbarHeight = appbarHeight;
  static StatusbarHeight = statusbarHeight;
  static HeaderHeight = appbarHeight + statusbarHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you used the UI constants, you should import like

`import {UIConstants} from './UIConstants'`

And not

`import UIConstants from './UIConstants'`